# Getting percentage difference between two numbers?

Tags: percentages

For example, if someone got a raise in salary and they were getting paid `80,000` and are now getting paid `85,000` how can you work out what percentage their raise was?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Percentage change : 100 % times the (Fractional change )

Fractional change : $\frac{85000-80000}{80000}$=$\frac{5000}{80000}$=$\dfrac{1}{16}$

Percentage change : $100\cdot\dfrac{1}{16}$% = $\dfrac{25}{4}$% = $6.25$%

Comment: I realize on the first line you have to do `original / difference` to get the fraction, but I don't quite understand the formula on the second line. What is the `dot` after the 100 for?

Comment: "$\cdot$" stands for multiplication or "times" it is 100 times $\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: and also the fractional change is difference or (change) / original

Comment: I think you mean 100% times fractional change?

Comment: Ok, so basically it's `difference / original * 100` ?

Comment: yes!${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please use dfrac instead of frac when there are a lot of terms in inline formatting. It looks more neat. :)

Comment: OK!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That is a raise of `$5000` per `$80000`. Percent means per hundred, so to convert that to a percent, we just solve `x/100 = 5000/80000` for x.

Comment: `x = 100*5000/80000 = 500000/80000 = 50/8 = 6.25`

Answer (score 3):

$100*\frac{new-original}{original}$

That will get the percent :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple Algebraic intuition : Let the percentage be $x$. Now ask $what\ \%$ of $80000$ gets added to $80000$ to get $85000$. Express it in the form of an equation.

$$\begin{align}
80000+\left(\frac{x}{100}\times80000\right)&=85000 \\
\implies\ \ \ x&=\dfrac{85000-80000}{80000}\times100 \\
&=6.25
\end{align}$$